# What is the purpose of the Aurelia typings folder structure in the skeleton-nav/skeleton-typescript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

What is the purpose of the typings -- browser and main folders as well as the custom_typings folder and their definitions?

They seem to be for the most part duplicates of each other and if I run the default typescript project I get a bunch of Duplicate identifier errors.

I understand that you can delete the browser and custom_typings folders and everything works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They seem to be for the most part duplicates of each other and if I run the default typescript project I get a bunch of Duplicate identifier errors.

## `main` vs. `browser`

- `main` follows the standard *main* resolution pattern for nodejs
- `browser` follows the `browserify` module resolution pattern.

In the absence of a `browser` key in package.json they would be equivalent. For the most part just use `main`.